# How to read the JSON value on console in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

i have  the following json value in console:

```
{"TokenID":"kuiHigen21","isError":false,"ErrorMessage":"","Result":[{"UserId":"153","FirstName":"Rocky","LastName":"Yadav","Email":"rocky@itg.com","ProfileImage":null,"ThumbnailImage":null,"DeviceInfoId":"12"}],"ErrorCode":900}
```

this is my server api :@"http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Login"
//api takes 5 parameters .
when i post data to server api values are posted to server and i get the above response in json format.

i want to parse the above the JSON value that i get in the response and save in sqlite database.

i am doing this code to parse the above JSON value:

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoadingNSURLConnection *)connection 
{ 
  NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] lengthwebData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     
     NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus); 

self.webData = nil; 

      SBJSON *parser =[[SBJSON alloc]init]; 

     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURLNSURL URLWithString"http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Login.json"]]; 

         NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 

  // Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response 

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

  //NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil]; 
  // parse the JSON response into an object   
// Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects 

NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];    


for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)  
 {     
// You can retrieve individual values using objectForKey on the status NSDictionary  
   // This will print the tweet and username to the console  

NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey"Login"],[status objectForKey"LoginKey"]);  

  [connection release];   [webData release]; 

}
```

Comment: hi @deanWombourne , this is my JSON file apitest[18318:207] { ErrorCode = 900; ErrorMessage = ""; Result = ( { DeviceInfoId = 12; Email = "rocky@itg.com"; FirstName = Rocky; LastName = Yadav; ProfileImage = "<null>"; ThumbnailImage = "<null>"; UserId = 153; } ); TokenID = 59nUniliob; isError = 0; } Can you please explain me how to parse the above JSON file and save the values in sqlite database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save this to a database with the help of a model class, Result

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSDictionary *result = [json_string JSONValue];
NSArray *values = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int index = 0; index<[values count]; index++) {
   NSMutableDictionary * value = [values objectAtIndex:index];
   Result * result = [[Result alloc] init];
   result.UserId = [value objectForKey:@"UserId"];
   result. FirstName = [value objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
   ...

   [results addObject:result];
   [result release]; 
}
```

use the array of results to save it to the database.

```
for (int index = 0; index<[results count]; index++) {
   Result * result = [results objectAtIndex:index];

   //save the object variables to database here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out some of the JSON parsers, my personal favourite is [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework). After you've included one of them in your project, where you've got your JSON response from your server:

```
// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response 

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSDictionary *result = [json_string JSONValue];
NSArray *statuses = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];
```

which will return your array of results (where each object in the array is an NSDictionary).

Comment: Hi @Daniel , this is my JSON file apitest[18318:207] {
    ErrorCode = 900;
    ErrorMessage = "";
    Result =     (
                {
            DeviceInfoId = 12;
            Email = "rocky@itg.com";
            FirstName = Rocky;
            LastName = Yadav;
            ProfileImage = "<null>";
            ThumbnailImage = "<null>";
            UserId = 153;
        }
    );
    TokenID = 59nUniliob;
    isError = 0;
}
Can you please explain me how to parse the above JSON file and save the values in sqlite database

Comment: @Rocky Well, use the json-framework, which adds the category method 'JSONValue' to NSString, so just call that method on your JSON object. I've edited my answer to make it clearer. Can't help you with inserting directly into sqlite db.

Comment: There are lots of json libraries, and maybe even a new one making it's way onto iOS shortly. But, as the OP is already using SBJSON, it seems sensible to stick the one parser.

Comment: don't be scared, `JSON` is a pretty simple RFC and implementations doesn't differs much. Except Microsoft .NET server/side one which has a different reading for some subtle parts, I would bet you can switch in less than an hour w/o any trouble and a good gain in performances/memory usage... > http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/